# Many-to-Many relationship but not allow to repeat a record

Tags: sql-server, database, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to design a Database where I have a comment table, project table and property table.  Each project can have one or more comments and the same logic for properties, but is not allow to have the same comment for property and project.
**Table name: Comments**
commentID PK NOT NULL,
commentBody NOT NULL

**Table name: Project**
projectID PK NOT NULL,
projectName NOT NULL,
projectType NOT NULL,
projectStatus NOT NULL,
...more

**Table name: Property**
propertyID PK NOT NULL,
propertyName NOT NULL,
propertySize NOT NULL,
propertyLandlord NOT NULL,
...more

**Table name: PropertyComments**
propertyCommentsID PK NOT NULL,
commentsID FK NOT NULL,
propertyID FK NOT NULL

**Table name: ProjectComments**
projectCommentsID PK NOT NULL,
commentsID FK NOT NULL,
projectID FK NOT NULL

So, with that approach you can repeat a comment, let's say commentID 1 could be for project and property.  What can I do to not allow a repeat comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally chose to have a join table based on database design best practices. 
**Update** - The requirement changed a little bit, the relationship should be One-To-Many.  So a project might have one or more notes, the projects can't share the same notes.

Answer (score 0):

Why create three separate tables for Comments, Create just one Table as Comments
with following columns:

commentID PK NOT NULL,

commentBody NOT NULL,

type, (whether property or project)

projectID FK NOT NULL,

propertyID FK NOT NULL

and then you can populate them using a stored procedure.

Comment: NitheshKHP - Using that approach I will have a null value in either propertyID column or projectID column. e.g. 1;'comments here';project;104; null.  Null FK is not good for performance I guess.

Comment: replace the null with a character '-' or something akin.